# How to build the SPIFFS and LFS filesystem? /local/spiffs; /local/lfs

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am building NodeMCU from the toolchain provided in the documentation, and I can make the firmware just fine, but I included a file in /local/spiffs as a test, but at the end of the build, I got a message that spiffs was out of space and the built was aborted...

I'm just wondering what /local/spiffs and /local/lfs are used for if not to build the SPIFFS image that gets built along with the firmware binaries...

If anyone also has details on how to use the LFS folder, as well, if it's even used that way, would also be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time,

Answer (score 1):

### First SPIFFS

- To build the spiffs file system you need to put files in **local/fs** as you
  probably surmised.  When you do this the basic make will create a spiffs image and place with the two *.bin files in **bin/**.
- You can also build a spiffs image by hand using

  tools/spiffsimage/spiffsimage
- As far as the size of the spiffs image, you do need to have space for the image when you build nodemcu.  For example, using make with no options in the main nodemcu-firmware directory will attempt to create images for a 32Mb (4MB), 8Mb (1MB, e.g., oft labeled esp-01S, or black esp-01), and finally 4Mb (512KB).  When one fails the process is terminated.
- You can build for the specific flash size you want, for example:

  - FLASHSIZE=32m make    <--- will build only the 4MB flash image pieces
  - FLASHSIZE=8m make     <--- for a black esp-01s with 1MB flash.

### Now for the LFS image

- When using generic **make** in the main **nodemcu-firmware** directory you need to first edit the file **app/include/user_config.h** and uncomment the two LFS commands.  You should set the size according to your needs -- for me this typically means 64KB as a lot of lua code can be stored in that space.
- If you want to build an lfs by hand you need a directory to place your files.  In that directory execute the command:

  luac.cross -o lfs.img -f *.lua

That will compile your files into the file lfs.img.

- If you are using LFS you should review **docs/getting-started.md** which has extremely useful information on a starting set of files for your lfs as well as information on using luac.cross as shown above. You of course have already looked at **docs/lfs.md**.

### Recommendation

A quick recommendation is to use the following process:

1. pick a flash size to target, say 32Mb (4MB)
2. uncomment the LFS lines in app/include/user_config.h and adjust the size
3. create a directory, say local/lfs and put the starter lfs files in it.
4. in local/lfs, execute  luac.cross -o lfs.img *.lua
5. move or copy lfs.img to local/fs  (note just **fs**) to make a spiffs image.
6. put the init.lua recommended into local/fs and make any changes to it you need.
7. finally put any other *.lua or LC (compiled) files you want into your local/fs
8. in the TOP_DIR (nodemcu-firmware) execute: **FLASHSIZE=4m make**
9. check out the files in **bin/**

Comment: You should note that all directories in this discussion are relative to the TOP_DIR.  That is the nodemcu-firmware directory.